# Install MariaDB without password prompt in Ubuntu

Tags: installation, ubuntu, mariadb

I need to install MariaDB server in Ubuntu without password prompt. For this purpose, I execute the following commands, but it doesn't gave me any progress. It again shows password prompt.

I used the following commands :

```
  export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
  echo mariadb-server-5.5 mariadb-server/root_password password mypass | debconf-set-selections
  echo mariadb-server-5.5 mariadb-server/root_password_again password mypass | debconf-set-selections
  sudo apt-get -y install mariadb-server
```

I also check some links in stack overflow, but it doesnot worked:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138636/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-natty-without-password-prompt-and-using-shell-variable-a

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739645/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-without-password-prompt

Please help me on this regard. Have any wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6):

A mixture of the mysql/mariadb-Nameing has worked for me:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password password rootpass'
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password_again password rootpass'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Ansible:

```
- name: Configure MariaDB Installation
  debconf:
    name: mariadb-server
    question: "{{ item }}"
    vtype: password
    value: "{{ db_root_pass }}"
  with_items:
    - mysql-server/root_password
    - mysql-server/root_password_again
  register: configure_install

- name: Install MariaDB with custom configuration
  apt:
    name: mariadb-server
    state: latest
    update_cache: true
  when: configure_install | success
  register: install_mariadb
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just use the mysql commands as it's backwards-compatible:

```
echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password test
mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password test' > /root/src/debconf.txt
debconf-set-selections /root/src/debconf.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

**Docker**

Put the following in your Dockerfile.

To set the root password to `rootpass`:

```
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-10.3 mysql-server/root_password password rootpass'"]
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-10.3 mysql-server/root_password_again password rootpass'"]
RUN apt-get -y install mariadb-server-10.3
```

Or, to set no/empty root password:

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install mariadb-server-10.3
```

(note I'm installing MariaDB 10.3, not 5.5)

Answer (score 0):

For me, in a clean debian 8.6, after installing and making useable sudo with

```
su <rootpassword><return>
apt-get -y install sudo
usermod -aG sudo <me>
```

shortening the above solutions to the following command worked:

```
sudo sh -c 'apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mariadb-server'
```

Afterwords, the mariadb-root has an empty password.