# Install MariaDB 10 on Ubuntu without prompt and no root password

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

Pretty much the same as [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/35866/10786) but I don't want to have a root password (this is just a dev machine).

Here's what I've got:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-10.0 mysql-server/root_password password PASS'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-10.0 mysql-server/root_password_again password PASS'
sudo apt-get install -y mariadb-server
```

This will install MariaDB silently but it will set the root password to "PASS". If I delete that it does a weird partial install because it's still trying to prompt me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the [link that Dimitar provided](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79257/how-do-i-install-mysql-without-a-password-prompt), the question itself hints at a solution - if you're putting this in a script, you could add the `SET PASSWORD` line with an empty password.

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-10.0 mysql-server/root_password password PASS'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-10.0 mysql-server/root_password_again password PASS'
sudo apt-get install -y mariadb-server
mysql -uroot -pPASS -e "SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('');"
```

That said, I recommend that you keep using passwords, even for dev environments. As [suggested on a related serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/a/103423), you could add lines to your my.cnf which contain the password, meaning that you can still simply fire up mysql by typing 'mysql':

```
[client]
user = root
password = s3kr1t
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do that with a cnf file. That works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need root password to achieve non-interactive installation of MariaDB 10.